# different usages of the phrase" No way is there"

Tags: idioms, inversion, existentials, negative-inversion

Extracted from Oxford Dictionary:

> 1. **There is no way** we could afford that sort of money.
> 2. **No way** am I going to drive them there

Would anyone please teach me if my revised sentences (#3 and #4) could be correct?

> 3. **No way** could we afford that sort of money.
> 4. **There is no way** I am going to drive them there.

And, what about the following? I mean if we could use the following instead of the bold parts?

- a. No way is there
- b. In no way

Any feedback would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Why make things complex? *There's no way...* must be way common in use.

Comment: Yes, your sentences are fine :-)  These examples are typical of **informal speech**, though, particularly the ones with *no way* at the beginning.

Comment: @MaulikV What makes you think the second sentences are more "complex" than the first ones?

Comment: Thanks. I am going to ask the question in another aspect in another question

Comment: +2 (If I could) This is way too interesting for ELU, but quite complex for ELL. Very interesting questions and examples. I'm not sure that 100 rep will get you an answer that will give your question justice - but here's the best place to try!! Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

Strong context or spoken informal conversation can cause parts of sentences to be omitted, because the missing parts are understood.  This can especially happen at the beginning or end of sentences.

> What are you doing?  (I am) Going to the park, I'll be back at 3pm.
>
> Who is sick?  My friend is (sick).
>
> He found a stick and was walking around like he was looking for a fight.  (He was) Scaring people.  He finally ran into someone that he didn't like and beat him (with the stick).

When you say "There is no way X", you are emphasizing that X will never happen.  It's an expression of strong denial.  Typically emphasis is on the *no way* in this phrase, so much so that the *there is* can be usually omitted without loss of meaning.

*In no way* can substitute for *there is no way* in the examples just fine and is equivalent.

Note that *there is no way* is a complete sentence and can be a full answer to a question.  In these situations it's not a good idea to use *no way* or *in no way,* it will sound weird most of the time.

> Can you fix it?  There is no way.
>
> Can you fix it?  No way.  (Sounds weird, like you are being curt or overly terse.)
>
> Can you fix it?  In no way can I fix it.  (Sounds like you are overemphasizing that you can't fix it.)

Comment: Nice answer - but I don't think you can just substitute "in no way" for "there is no way". I don't know if you noticed but in you *in no way* sentence, you reversed the subject and the auxiliary verb!

Comment: True.  You can say "I can in no way fix it" or "In no way can I fix it" - the helping verb may need to move.  I think "in no way" can directly modify a verb where "there is no way" can't, it's a complete sentence or clause.